# Поймать ошибку C++ кода в GO

Tags: c++, c, golang

Есть функция описанная в C коде, которая интегрирована в Golang, например:

```
C.myFunc(someArgv)
```

На стороне кода C++ описана что может быть ошибка

```
    try {
        someFuncInCpp();
    } catch (std::exception &e) {
        std::cerr << "Error" << std::endl;
    }
```

Стандартный пакет Golang - C не дает подсказок и предположений что там есть вероятная ошибка. Но при определенном поведении ошибка происходит.

Вопрос: как на стороне Golang описать что именно эта функция C на стороне кода C++ может вызвать ошибку и при такой ситуации ошибку создать в приложении Golang, чтобы работать с ней нужным образом ?

Дополнительно: внедрение кода C++ в Golang у меня успешно работает, поэтому в моем вопросе нет ошибок с указанием C/C++

**UPD:** я нашел хороший пример, думаю он меня устраивает
https://artem.krylysov.com/blog/2017/04/13/handling-cpp-exceptions-in-go/

Comment: При смешении си и с++ кода - получается машинный код. И даже delphi или object pascal сгенерирует тоже очень похожий (во многих случаях идеинтичный) машинный код. Вы можете из си подключить функцию написаную на делфи или ассемблере... но в итоге нет встроеной возможности отличить си с++ делфи ассемблер. Это будет просто машинный код.

Comment: Хотя теоретически, если функции экспортные, то у си и с++ по разному идёт построение "экспортных" имен функций. Теоретически можно определить по стеку вызовов в какой функции возникла ошибка, найти её в таблице экспорта (если она там есть) и по экспортному имени узнать си или с++ она, ну это такое... годится разве что вы сами все функции делаете и плюс там тоже есть некоторые тонкости. Это довольно костыльное решение.

Comment: типа при объявлении функции указать что есть объект ошибки по указателю и при появлении ошибки по указателю записать ее и потом на голанг вытащить ?

Comment: Как вариант.... Исключения в си и в с++ - немного  по-разному генерируются. Возможно есть смысл делать над си функцией с++ обвертку try-catch, и перегенерировать исключение (через `throw new exception` или что-то такое) - тогда на выходе исключение если будет - то гарантировано плюсовое и go увидит исключение нормально.

Comment: Если у вас С функция, то откуда взялась сторона С++ кода? Если это на самом деле С функция, то с++ исключений в ней быть не может, а если это С++ функция недекорированным именем, то ее нельзя использовать в go.

Comment: Я не знаю как Go формируется "обьект" ошибки для си. И можно ли из него вытрусить каку-то полезную информацию, или ту информацию которая вам нужна.

Comment: Начнем с того, что в Си нет исключений (ошибок, как вы их называете), этот механизм реализован только в С++. Насколько я вижу в коде примера, в нем вызывается функция, которая может бросить исключение. Это исключение как раз перехватывается и обрабатывается в данном примере кода. Выше оно не распространяется. Поэтому не понятно, что именно вас тут беспокоит

Comment: @user7860670, я специально написал что нет никаких противоречий. C код содержит в себе заголовки функций который импортируются в C++ код, а сам C код импортируется в GO. поэтому ваша претензия о том почему и как - не принимаются. Я на работе на базе этого реализовал мощный функционал.

Comment: "внедрение кода C++ в Golang у меня успешно работает" - а не должно. Так что вы явно делаете что-то не так, либо принимаете желаемое за действительное. Так или иначе, в вопросе отсутствует [mcve], так что ничего конкретного по этой ситуации сказать нельзя.

Comment: @user7860670 прежде чем распыляться советую хотя бы в доки заглянуть https://golang.org/doc/go1.2#cgo_and_cpp

Comment: ¿А вы сами-то туда заглядывали?

Comment: @АлексейСеливерстов в вопросе недостаточно примера для воспроизведения проблемы. не могли бы добавить?